# Can top user change their display picture?

Tags: discussion

Recetenly #stackmagento gives excellent gift(Top user swag) to top 72 users. Can those user change their display picture along with t-shirt?

I think it looks really cool.

What do you think guys ?

Comment: as soon i get will change it..

Comment: This should be person's choice. However I wonder where is my gift !!! I think @AmitBera got his gift. Waiting for it

Comment: Yes, It's person choice, but I think It looks really good if we can change. Also, hope you will get your gift with in short time. :) @RajeevKTomy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is up to each user.
Some of the users already changed their profile picture to include the shirt even before the shirts were delivered (using their awesome Photoshop skills).
If it's worth something, I will not change mine mainly because I'm lazy.

Comment: awesome Photoshop skills   :D  :D  totally agree

Comment: lazy....? Really...........? : )

Comment: about some things I actually am.

Comment: I think expect Magento...:)